# What is the fee policy suggested by the mainline bitcoin client?

Tags: transaction-fees

The online wallet [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info) allows for the fee policy to be customised:

[image]

The "Normal" policy states

```
Follow the fee policy suggested by the mainline bitcoin client.
```

What is the fee policy suggested by the mainline bitcoin client explicitly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees

> Otherwise, the reference implementation will round up the transaction size to the next thousand bytes and add a fee of 0.1 mBTC (0.0001 BTC) per thousand bytes.

So the rate is 0.1 mBTC for each thousand bytes (rounded up) the transaction is.